# C++ operator error

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword

getting this error:

C:\CodeBlocks\kool\praks3\vector.h|62|error: passing 'const Vector<2u>' as 'this' argument of 'std::string Vector::toString() [with short unsigned int n = 2u]' discards qualifiers|

with this code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <unsigned short n>
class Vector {
    public:
        std::vector<float> coords;

        Vector();
        Vector(std::vector<float> crds);


        float distanceFrom(Vector<n> v);

        std::string toString();

        template <unsigned short m>
        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Vector<m>& v);
};



    template <unsigned short n>
std::string Vector<n>::toString() {
    std::ostringstream oss;

    oss << "(";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        oss << coords[i];
        if(i != n - 1) oss << ", ";
    }
    oss << ")";
    return oss.str();
}

template <unsigned short m>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Vector<m>& v) {
    out << v.toString(); // ERROR HEEEERE
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Congrats. So, what is your question? I don't see a single question mark in the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the `toString` method `const`:

```
std::string toString() const;
```

and

```
template <unsigned short n>
std::string Vector<n>::toString() const{...}
```

That's because you add the `const` qualifier to the `Vector` in the `operator<<`. You are only allowed to call `const` qualified methods on `const` qualified objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your vector is declared as const, while your toString operator is not a const method.
Therefore, calling this method is forbidden with a const instant.
If you do not edit the vector while converting it to string, you should declare it as a const method :

```
std::string toString() const;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `const Foo`, you can only invoke `const` member functions on it.  So declare it as `std::string toString() const`.